# PersistMap in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, template-haskell

I'm using Yesod to design a website, and I'd like to use the PersistMap data type to map entries to text names. However, I can't seem to find any examples of how to declare a PersistMap field in the config/models file.

When I try

```
entryName [Text] Map
```

it seems to just make a [Text] variable, but when I do

```
entryName (Text, Text) Map
```

or

```
entryName [(Text, Text)] Map
```

I get a syntax error.

How can I declare a PersistMap entry in my config/models file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Haskell code, you can declare a type synonym, e.g.:

```
type TextPairs = [(Text, Text)]
```

Then use that synonym in your model definition.

Comment: What file would I declare this in, Foundation.hs? Thanks!

Comment: No, Model.hs.  (dummy characters)